# opensc 32 bit for windows does it create opensc-pkcs11.dll file?

Tags: opensc

OpenSC 32 bit for windows installation does not create file  opensc-pkcs11.dll  in c:\windows\system32, but the installation document says it does, is this a bug?  or am I missing anything?  I tried download different versions, none of them created this file.

Answer (score 2):

32 bit installation file is creating pkcs-dll in C:\Windows\SysWOW64  and not in  c:\Windows\System32  as the documentation says.